# Loop many times on many airflow tasks on one dag

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am creating one dag that will have following structure of tasks. This DAG will be schedule to run
on everyday at 1:00 AM UTC time.
Get rows from database ---- loop on rows to run many task that require each row data.

For example I have method in my DAG that call MySQL database and return many rows .Each row data I have to pass in 4 task as a parameter. I have followed some  google search docs but that is not running correctly.

return_db_result  is method to get result from Cloud SQL in GCP.

```
def return_result():
    db_engine_connection = create_cloud_sql_connection()
    session = get_db_session(db_engine_connection)
    result = session.query(Scheduled).filter(Scheduled.job_status == "Scheduled").all()
    session.commit()
    return result
```

I tried using for loop like something following

```
for row in return_result():
    op1 = operator({ param=row.id})
    op2 = operator({ param=row.id})
    op3 = operator({ param=row.id})
    op4 = operator({ param=row.id})
    op1 >> op2 >> op3 >> op4
```

But these task does not show on airflow UI.

Comment: DAG structure needs to be static or slowly changing. If you are expecting the DAG structure to be change on every run that is not a good practice. To solve your specific issue you need task_id param to be unique. I can't tell from your example what field in `row` is unique.

Comment: Thanks Elad, task_id can be change. like 'task_name'+row.primary_id , But I am not sure how to iterate this,

Comment: You didn't answer the most basic concern.if you are expecting that in one run you will have 8 operators in next 5 and in the next 6 - Airflow is not the tool for you. Please explain what is the content of `row` per each run. Is it a static or near static table ?

Comment: Table contain three column id , date , status, operators are constant let say 5 operator in every loop and that will not be changing. only I need to pass different parameters to operators in each loop.so dag structure will not be changing only operators parameter will be changing for each loop.

Comment: it's a bit strange to use the same operator with the same params in that sequence but I assume you are only looking for the structure. Posted answer how you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments assuming your operator is:

```
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 input_id,
                 input_date,
                 input_status,
                 *args, **kwargs):

        super(MyOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.input_id=input_id
        self.input_date=input_date
        self.input_status=input_status

    def execute(self, context):
        pass
```

You can use it as follows:

```
start_op = DummyOperator(task_id='start_op')
for row in return_db_result:
    op1 = MyOperator(task_id=f"op1_{row.id}", input_id=row.id, input_date=row.date, input_status=row.status)
    op2 = MyOperator(task_id=f"op2_{row.id}", input_id=row.id, input_date=row.date, input_status=row.status)
    op3 = MyOperator(task_id=f"op3_{row.id}", input_id=row.id, input_date=row.date, input_status=row.status)
    op4 = MyOperator(task_id=f"op4_{row.id}", input_id=row.id, input_date=row.date, input_status=row.status)
    start_op >> op1 >> op2 >> op3 >> op4
```

Comment: Sorry for late response I will test it today and will update you

Comment: I am using same code as mentioned by you but getting ×DAG "teloopstack3" seems to be missing error. Look like we can not iterate on return result.

Comment: You didnt mentioned how you get the return_db_result. My advice is edit the quesion and explain everything from the start. You asked about specific part in the middle of your DAG so its diffecult to understand the limitation. In general the above code will work if the query to the db is included in the parsing loop of the scheduler. This will cause havey load on the database but I assumed this is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks I have updated question. Please take a look. I did not get parsing loop of the scheduler.?

Comment: OK so this is not a good practice. Airflow parse your dag code according to min_file_process_interval. this means that every time airflow scan your DAG it will open a session to Cloud SQL. This will create a very heavy load on the DB. You should avoid interacting with databases outside of operators scope. For your use case and like you say the dag is mostly static I don't understand why you need this loop to begin with. I recommend you changing the return_db_result to list or json file. Inside MyOperator you can open connection to Cloud SQL to fetch the value you need.

Comment: Thanks I understand that but if you use MyOperator  to open connection to Cloud SQL, we need to do this in every MyOperator ,

Comment: I am not sure how to do this and use ,I do not want to save this db result in XCOM. Please explain.I tried to use one PythonOperator and make db connection and get result., on this result inside PythonOperator I used for loop toiterate and kept all other operator but that was not working. Airflow was considering only MyOperator and ignoring other Operator inside this.

Comment: Again this is all theoretical as you didn't really share the flow but you don't need to use xcom. MyOperator can open connection to DB using hook - do whatever needs to be done. I  think your issue combine different type of problems related to the design of the ETL using Airflow and best practices. This is too big for a single stackoverflow. Sorry I can't help further.